# Filling out pdf fields in R using staplr

Tags: r, forms, pdf, field

I am new to R and I have a problem (no I not and alcoholic :D).

I have a fillable pdf form (available from [HERE](https://isir.justice.cz/isir/forms/Konecna_zprava.pdf), it is government document). I want to be able to automatically fill the field forms with generated data, so I dont have to write them out.

I have found that the staplr package should be able to do it by using commands like:

```
pdfFile = system.file("/home/qumive/OneDrive/pdf/zprava.pdf", package = "staplr")

fields <- get_fields(pdfFile)
```

and then manually using the field names to edit them.

but I have problem with reading the PDF. I have installed all dependencies(?) such as JAVA, pdftk, rJava and such, but when I use code like this:

```
 library(staplr)


pdfFile = system.file("/home/qumive/OneDrive/pdf/zprava.pdf", package = "staplr")

fields <- get_fields(pdfFile)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in normalizePath(input_filepath, mustWork = TRUE) : 
  path[1]="": No such file or directory
```

I have renamed the pdf to zprava.pdf.

Do you have any idea why this is not working? Thank you in advance!!

## update 1

So I tried to load different pdf and it works perfectly fine...seems like there is problem with some sort of .xml layer or something and that is why I can't grab the field names for editing.

Also tried to to edit it with Adobe DC PRO and it says that to edit the document you need to use LiveCycle Designer. But that is some sort of enterprise app, that doesnt seem to be part of the creative cloud. So right now I am sort of stuck :D